# Android Kotlin Range slider setting values programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, rangeslider

I've added a RangeSlider to android Kotlin app and I'm trying to set the values read from settings. Settings are fine but when I set those to slider eg. `slider.values[0] = 12.0F` the value doesn't change. With normal slider it's ok. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it by calling setValues(x,y) with two values to enable two thumbs.